# how to get current directory's excel file only using python

Tags: python, pathlib

I want to get all excel file names under my current .ipynb file path.
I tried this:

```
files = [f for f in pathlib.Path().glob("*.xlsx")]
```

It returns this:

```
[PosixPath('xxxxx.xlsx'),
 PosixPath('xxxx.xlsx')]
```

However, I want the result to be like this:

```
['xxxxx.xlsx',
 'xxxx.xlsx']
```

And I also tried:

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir() if os.path.isfile(f)]
```

This will contain all files but I only want excel files.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pathlib.Path.name`.

```py
files = [f.name for f in pathlib.Path().glob("*.xlsx")]
```

returns `['xxxxx.xlsx','xxxx.xlsx']`

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.name)

Answer (score 0):

You can just "typecast" the resulting PosixPath to strings like;

```py
files = [str(f) for f in pathlib.Path().glob("*.xlsx")]
```

Comment: I get an error trying to run this: `SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call`.

Comment: str() was in wrong  place  - fixed

Answer (score 0):

you almost got it in the last attempt, you only have to modify the `if` part:

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir() if os.path.isfile(f) and f.endswith('.xlsx')]
```

if you work on windows, you can also write `f.lower().endswith('.xlsx')`

Answer (score 0):

files = [f for f in os.listdir() if os.path.isfile(f) and '.xlsx' in f]